# OkHttp with GzipRequestInterceptor causes 400 Bad Request from Jetty server

Tags: java, android, jetty, retrofit, okhttp

My Android app is using `com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0` with `com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0` as a client.

**Update** Server is `Jetty 9.3.0.v20150612` running on `Java 1.8.0_45-b1`. I've tested the same server with another app, a compressed request was delivered successfully.

API has a command with a `@Body Map<String, Object> payload`, converted automatically to JSON. **It works well when sent uncompressed**, but it's a 92k JSON body, so it better be compressed.

I've followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors#rewriting-requests) and created a GzipRequestInterceptor, fixed the content length adding a buffer as instructed [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/350) and installed it to the RestAdapter -

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.networkInterceptors().add(new GzipRequestInterceptor());

// Create a very simple REST adapter which points the GitAPI endpoint.
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(BuildConfig.MBE_SERVER_HOST)
        .setClient(new OkClient(client))
        .build();
```

For some reason, it now throws a Bad Request error -

```
retrofit.RetrofitError: 400 Bad Request
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:388)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:397)
        at $Proxy1.report(Unknown Source)
        at mypackage.ReportRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(ReportRequest.java:40)
        at mypackage.Request$1.doInBackground(Request.java:36)
        at mypackage.Request$1.doInBackground(Request.java:32)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Here's the interceptor -

```
public class GzipRequestInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request originalRequest = chain.request();
        if (originalRequest.body() == null || originalRequest.header("Content-Encoding") != null) {
            return chain.proceed(originalRequest);
        }

        Request compressedRequest = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                .header("Content-Encoding", "gzip")
                .method(originalRequest.method(), requestBodyWithContentLength(gzip(originalRequest.body())))
                .build();
        return chain.proceed(compressedRequest);
    }

    private RequestBody gzip(final RequestBody body) {
        return new RequestBody() {
            @Override
            public MediaType contentType() {
                return body.contentType();
            }

            @Override
            public long contentLength() {
                return -1; // We don't know the compressed length in advance!
            }

            @Override
            public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
                BufferedSink gzipSink = Okio.buffer(new GzipSink(sink));
                body.writeTo(gzipSink);
                gzipSink.close();
            }
        };
    }

    private RequestBody requestBodyWithContentLength(final RequestBody body) throws IOException {

        final Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
        body.writeTo(buffer);

        return new RequestBody() {
            @Override
            public MediaType contentType() {
                return body.contentType();
            }

            @Override
            public long contentLength() {
                return buffer.size();
            }

            @Override
            public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
                ByteString snapshot = buffer.snapshot();
                sink.write(snapshot);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

What's wrong?

**Update - Server configuration**

Not sure how relevant it is, since it enables compression for responses, here's web.xml with GzipFilter enabled -

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>mimeTypes</param-name>
        <param-value>text/html,text/plain,text/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/css,application/javascript,image/svg+xml,application/json</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>minGzipSize</param-name>
        <param-value>500</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

etc/jetty-gzip.xml -

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  <Get id="next" name="handler" />
  <Set name="handler">
    <New id="GzipHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler">
      <Set name="handler"><Ref refid="next" /></Set>
      <Set name="minGzipSize"><Property name="jetty.gzip.minGzipSize" deprecated="gzip.minGzipSize" default="2048"/></Set>
      <Set name="checkGzExists"><Property name="jetty.gzip.checkGzExists" deprecated="gzip.checkGzExists" default="false"/></Set>
      <Set name="compressionLevel"><Property name="jetty.gzip.compressionLevel" deprecated="gzip.compressionLevel" default="-1"/></Set>
      <Set name="excludedAgentPatterns">
        <Array type="String">
          <Item><Property name="jetty.gzip.excludedUserAgent" deprecated="gzip.excludedUserAgent" default=".*MSIE.6\.0.*"/></Item>
        </Array>
      </Set>

      <Set name="includedMethods">
        <Array type="String">
          <Item>GET</Item>
          <Item>POST</Item>
        </Array>
      </Set>

    </New>
  </Set>
</Configure>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your webserver doesn't support compressed requests.

Comment: I've added my server configuration. Pretty sure it does, but I'll make sure.

Comment: This may be true, I've posted a question about Jett's server configuration - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31555633/jetty-responds-with-400-bad-request-when-request-content-type-is-gzip

Comment: Someone from Jetty's support team confirmed that it doesn't support Content-Encoding: gzip for incoming requests.